# What is the difference between absmiddle and middle

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for the difference between the absmiddle and middle when using in the attribute align like this :

```
<span align='middle'></span>
```

or

```
<span align='absmiddle'></span>
```

I don't understand what is the difference and I don't understand which I have to use and when ?

Comment: "I don't understand which I have to use and when" — Neither. The align attribute is deprecated. We've had CSS for almost two decades now.

Comment: Why this is deprecated ?

Comment: In the case you decide to use stylesheet, here's a list of available values for `vertical-align` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align (P.S. For horizontal alignment you have the `text-align` property.)

Comment: @Buisson — Because we have CSS now.

Comment: Yes but css is not very easy for the vertical align ... because there is a lot of property and not work on all web browser ...

Comment: @Buisson — Support for `vertical-align` has been excellent among browsers for years.

Comment: @Quentin except for some 2.2 android browsers (2y ago...)

Comment: http://www.web-sheeps.com/rec/69-Image-vertical-align-with-CSS,-avoid-abs

Comment: I have found [something](http://goo.gl/gsJXbL)

Comment: @YvesHendseth, You are redirecting to Google. :(

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have added a link which give detail description of the absmiddle and go to w3school for middle. From  there ,you will understand the difference

http://www.pagetutor.com/align/align_absmiddle.html

Comment: and one day that your link dies you'll not get an up-vote for sure!

Comment: so you should paste your sample here, @BalajiG